# python pip install not working on windows

Tags: python, django, windows, python-2.7, pip

I have python 2.7.10 installed  on windows and I am trying to install Django on the commandline with the following command:

```
C:/users/user/myproject> python pip install django
```

This displays the following error:

```
python: can't open file 'pip' [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Python is installed in `C:\Python27` and the `PATH` environment variable is also set to that.

Why is pip not working?

Comment: you have to install pip first http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/stable/installing/

Comment: you have to ensure that `C:\Python27\Scripts` is in your system environment variable `%PATH%`

Comment: I have a similar issue in a conda environment under Windows. I would usually install a local packages with `pip install -e .`. The command works fine, I get the message ´successfully installed {package}´, though ´python -c "import {package}"´ does not find it then.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since Python 2.7.9 `pip` is [included](https://docs.python.org/2/installing/) when python is installed.

However the `scripts` subfolder of your python installation might not be added to your `PATH` environment variable, and hence inaccessible by just typing `pip install`. However as long as your `python` executable is on the path, [you can use the `python -m` flag to execute the `pip` module as a script](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/runpy.html):

```
python -m pip install SomePackage
```

This should work from the command line as long as `python` is on `PATH`.

If you would like to use `pip` directly from the `cmd.exe` prompt you need to add the `scripts` directory to your `PATH` environment variable:

```
SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\Python27\scripts
```

Comment: I was able to install packages. Could you please explain the use of -m as without using I got error only, and when used it successfully ran.

Answer (score 0):

Some times in windows it especially needs Microsoft visual c++ compiler. If such error persists you can verify the log file and If needed you can download here
http://aka.ms/vcpython27